# Prioritize RAM access Linux

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, real-time

I have an FPGA acquisition board that streams data to the PC through PCIe2 4 lanes. I managed to get the full specs bandwidth of ~1.6 GB/s. Data are coming into the FPGA from ADCs at 1.5 GB/s ad I used a relative small FIFO (16k points) just for buffering. On the PC side I have 32GB of DDR4-2133 and I locked and dma mapped 16GB of it. When I start to transfer data, the PCIe root complex starts to throttle the channel and sometimes the throttling is so intense that the cumulative wait reaches ~1ms. By that I mean I get grant to transfer one TLP, wait for ~1us, one TLP, wait etc... and eventually the FIFO gets full and I start to lose data and I cannot increase the FIFO size. There's a correlation between the heaviness of data throttling and the workload of the OS, especially ethernet, audio, graphic traffic. I was looking for if there is a way to forcibly prioritize the RAM access.

In one scenario those streamed data will eventually be written to disk, hopefully real-time, and instead of streaming data to the RAM and then opening and writing to a file, I was wondering if there is a way to directly map a file to an already present memory region so I will only need to force a ram flush.

In another scenario, data will eventually be real time processed by the CPU. Right now I'm running the user space code that deals with the driver in a thread with a dedicated core (I have 10 cores HT). Whenever a block of data is streamed I get an interrupt and another thread (processing thread), in another dedicated core, gets woken up and starts processing the data. Before doing this, kernel code syncs the dma mapped buffer for cpu access and this takes time, not much but at the data rate I'm working with is significant. In principle I guess I can avoid this because the CPU is not going to access the same location at the same time as the FPGA, is that right?
Then the processing thread starts to read and process the data while the streaming keeps going. Instead of using a for cycle to read data from ram to cache, is there a way to force a large amount of memory to be transferred to the cache?

I know I'm dealing with humongous data throughput.

Last question: before digging into a RT linux OS, do you think I will have some advantages?

Thanks